# Chart is not working on offline

Tags: javascript, html, charts, html5-canvas

I need a multi screen chart on html5 in offline. I used Google Chart and that was perfect, but It's could not work offline for their terms of service but I need Chart in offline.

Please watch the attached file.
 [Please watch this attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a7gJ.png)   . I need that type chart in offline.

So tell me how do I fix that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by downloading required JS file locally and use them to generate chart for example, for D3.js all you need to do is download d3.js file and use code shown in link to generate chart.

Most of the chart library will work if you download relative js file and use those downloaded js file path instead using CDNs.

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

Comment: Sorry i have edited my answer please check above link

Comment: Tell me how do I create self chart using javascript, jquery ?